# Motor on-off circuit with Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, relay, dc-motor

Below is my circuit diagram. I want to on and off my two motors inside. However, I want to make circuit better and replace two Diode between TIP120 and Digital output. I want to change the relay to more common type as well. My motors are needed to switch on for around 2 hours. 
What others thing should I change? Could you help me?

Thank you. 
[image]

I updated my circuit diagram. Could you all take a look? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! "better" isn't an engineering term here. What problems are you experiencing and what do you aim to improve?

Comment: BANG! take a look at where the collectors of the BJTs are connected. (shorting out the 12V supply). Also base current should be controlled through a resistor not a diode.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thank You. I shouldn't connect collectors to 12V right? How about other mistakes. Thank you.